# how to print float array list

Tags: c#

how to make two arrays list the first one to read and the second one to print the float number

Comment: Why would you want to do that? what is your problem? Is something not working as you expect? What do you expect and what do you observe? Please [edit] your question to add these details to your question after you have read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: no there is not any problem but the dr need to use in for loop but i dont know how to do it in for loop

Comment: If you have a new question, please create a new question rather than completely changing this question

Comment: i cannot ask again. why i dont know .im new here

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive function, for example:

```
public void ReadLine()
{   
    var read = Console.ReadLine();

    a.Add(read);

    if (read != "|")
        ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: the dr need it in forr loop

Answer (score 0):

With a for loop you can do:

```
for (;;)
{
    read = Console.ReadLine();
    a.Add(read);
    if (read == "|")
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what to write in for()?

Comment: Just as I typed it `for(;;)`! Nothing is missing from my example.

Comment: It is an infinite loop that will never end, unless a `break` statement is met. Have a look at the [MSDN-Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx).

Comment: what is the difference between double[] aa = new double[a.Count]; and double[] aa = new double[a.Count-2];

Comment: You should not ask questions in comments!